# FBSDK ShareDialog is showing "Invalid App ID: The provided app ID does not look like a valid app ID."

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to use the FBSDK ShareDialog in my react-native app (just IOS for now) and when I open the ShareDialog I keep seeing the 'Invalid App ID' message. I added the specified code to my info.plist file and my Facebook app is not in sandbox mode; I have not been able to find a solution to this issue.

My ShareDialog code:

```
const shareLinkContent = {
  contentType: 'link',
  contentUrl: "http://google.com",
  contentDescription: "The world's most popular search engine"
};

ShareDialog.setMode("webview");
ShareDialog.canShow(shareLinkContent).then(function(canShow) {
    if (canShow) {
      return ShareDialog.show(shareLinkContent);
    } else {
      self.props.navigation.navigate('Notifications', { notifications: updatedNotifications });
    }
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.isCancelled) {
      console.log('Share cancelled');
    } else {
      console.log('Share success with postId: ' + result.postId);
    }
  },
  function(error) {
    console.log('Share fail with error: ' + error);
  }
);
```

My info.plist file:

```
 version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>fb{ My App's Facebook App ID }</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>{ My App's Facebook App ID }</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>{ My App's Display Name }</string>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>{ My App's Display Name }</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

[This is how the error appears in my emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjFrU.jpg)

Comment: `key>FacebookAppID</key> ` you have to insert valid App Id . Which you have to create from Facebook Developer `<string>fb149XXXxxxx</string>`

Comment: Yeah in my code I have my Facebook App ID in the `<string></string>` tags, I just removed it from the code since this is a public question.

Comment: And you removed the { .. } around the actual value as well, right? (Those are only used to signal “this is a placeholder that needs to be replaced” ...)

Comment: Yes, in my code it is just the value, like `<string>12345678910</string>`.
I pasted it in exactly how it's specified in the 'Get Started' docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the part that Facebook was refusing was not my App ID, but accessing 'webview' from a native app. Starting running the app off of my actual device and removed the `ShareDialog.setMode("webview");` - worked like a charm! I imagine this is because of Facebook restricting API / SDK access recently.